# Jquery 2.1 - wait for the two ajax calls to end and then destroy element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my function there are two ajax calls. When both ajax calls are finished, **.popup-loading** needs to be removed. How can I do this?

Function:

```
// Create login/create user panel
function createPopupUser() {
    var
        body      = $('body'),
        baseUrl   = body.data('base-url'),
        // start of user panel
        userPanel = '<div class="popup-container">';
        userPanel += '<div class="popup-loading">';
        userPanel += '</div>';
        userPanel += '<div class="popup-panel">';
        userPanel += '<div class="popup-new-user">';
        userPanel += '</div>';
        userPanel += '<div class="popup-login">';
        userPanel += '</div>';
        userPanel += '</div>';
        userPanel += '</div>';
        // end of user panel

    $('body').prepend(userPanel);

    var newUserResponse, loginResponse;
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: baseUrl + 'users/create',
        async: false,
        success : function(text)
        {
            newUserResponse = text;
        }
    });

    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: baseUrl + 'users/login',
        async: false,
        success : function(text)
        {
            loginResponse = text;
        }
    });

    var popup = $('body').find('.popup-container');
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() { popup.find('.popup-loading').remove(); });
    popup.find('.popup-new-user').append(newUserResponse);
    popup.find('.popup-login').append(loginResponse);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Deferred`:

```
$def1 = $.ajax({...});
$def2 = $.ajax({...});
// Do stuff
$.when($def1, $def2).done(function() {
    // Remove loading indicator
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use promises, and specifically the [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) method to synchronise the two:

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax(...)

var ajax2 = $.ajax(...)

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function() {
    popup.find('.popup-loading').remove();
})
```

p.s. lose the `async: false` option!   It's considered bad practise these days, and in any event (no pun intended) it's incompatible with using promises.